# Difference bw 'has been my favorite' & 'has easily been my favorite'

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, difference

I am confused about use of **Has Been** specially among these two sentences. 
If I say

> It has been my favorite.

and

> It has easily been my favorite.

than the meaning both sentence is changing or not?

According to me

- First sentence - Something is my favorite since long time & still favorite.
- Second sentence- Something became my favorite easily.

May know the exact meaning of these sentence?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The addition of the word *easily* to the sentence implies that, of the other available options, there was no contest in which was your favourite - the choice was obvious.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should replace the I with it as you are referring to something else so it will be:

> It has been my favorite.
>   It has easily been my favorite.

By adding more words in the second sentence you are emphasising the meaning of the sentence more. It also means it easily became your favorite.